# How can I write this same statement using for loops instead of while loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

The idea here is to learn how to apply different methods to the same problem in order to learn and see the differences

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer value-> ");
int k = input.nextInt();
input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a larger value-> ");
int j = input.nextInt();
int i = k;

while (i <= j)
 {
  if (i%2 == 0)
 {
 System.out.println(i);
 }
 i++;
 }
```

I am trying this, but it is clearly wrong, how can I fix it, or where should i look?

```
      for(i<=j;i % 2 ==0;i++)
      {
      System.out.println(i);
      }}
```

Comment: Please indent your code in future - it makes it *much* easier to read.

Comment: you really don't know how to translate this to a for loop? what have you tried?

Comment: Think about what you have, the for loop contains three parts. The first part is the variable declaration. You could put the variable you are using inside the loop into it. the second part is the condition, which you do already have. The las part contains the operation that has to be done after each iteration. Think about what the last thing is that you are doing in your while loop. Simply combine the three parts that you already have into the three parts, and you changed the while to a for loop.

Comment: So i have to initialize within the for loop, is that what you mean?

Comment: Review the [for loop tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: like doing  for ( i = j ; i % 2 = = 0; i++)

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe the condition you are using in your loop isn´t what you are looking for, think about what you did in the while loop. It has to iterate over the range of `j - k` and not as long as `i` is even(that changes at least after the first iternation since you add one to i after after each). That should be the condition for your print.

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe You can take a look at my solution below on how to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: yes i did, thank you.... I am also reading the tutorial, very helpful.... thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing conversion from one loop to the other, it will be much easier if we first understand the intention of the original loop. From ***what you have***:

```
while (i <= j){
    if (i%2 == 0)
        System.out.println(i);
     i++;
}
```

In **plain English**, it means:
From the **lower bound** input to the **upper bound** input, print out all the **even numbers** (inclusive of zeroes).

Now based on that, we write a **for-loop**.

```
for(int x=k, x<=j; x++) //k is lower bound,  j is upper bound
    if(x % 2 == 0)      //if current number is even or 0
        System.out.println(x);    //print that number
```

Comment: thank you, i was struggling understanding, but your answer helped!

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe If you have more doubts, let me know by leaving it in the comments. If everything is clear, you can consider accepting my solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer value-> ");
int k = input.nextInt();
input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a larger value-> ");
int j = input.nextInt();
int i = k;

for (;i <= j;i++) {
  if (i%2 == 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Translated in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = k; i <= j; i++) {
   if (i%2 ==0) {
   System.out.println(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: I love how people vote down on the answer but don t even attempt to help or at least say something useful